# What is this M-q behaviour in Emacs 26.1 message mode

Tags: fill-paragraph, message-mode

Since updating to Emacs 26.1. message mode was changed so that `M-q` does something unexpected.  I have `fill-column` and `message-fill-column` both set to 72 and pressing `M-q` on this text:

[image]

turns it into this text:

[image]

It seems that in other modes `M-q` does what it usually does.  In particular, if I switch this buffer to text mode I can get the expected formatting.

Update: I have researched the issue. It appears as if in message mode the function `message-fill-paragraph` is called. This function was slightly changed from 25.3 to 26.1.  But essentially it just calls `message-newline-and-reformat` which actually does something else. I can't find the reason for the totally unexpected behaviour of `message-fill-paragraph`.  It does not what it says it should do and for example seems totally unrelated to the value of `message-fill-column`.

Comment: What does `C-h k M-q` tell you in that context? Then look at the definition of the command that it says is bound to `M-q` there.

Comment: Aha, right. It runs `fill-paragraph` which runs `fill-paragraph-function` if that variable is not nil. Indeed, in message mode it is set to `message-fill-paragraph` from `message.el`. I'm can't see through that function, though. I can replace it with fill-paragraph, though.

Comment: You can post the answer you found as an answer (to your own question), showing others what you did to fix the problem. (And you can accept your own answer.) Be aware that comments can be deleted at any time - what helps people is to have a question and an answer (or several answers).

Comment: I can't solve it.

Comment: Do you have the `mail-header-separator` which typically is `--text follows this line--` in your message?  If not your paragraph possibly gets handled as a field.

Comment: @MarcoWahl Yes, you solved it ! My separator comes from the external editor plugin for Thunderbird and is different, so I had to customize `mail-header-separator` to match. Please post as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the default settings `M-q` effectively calls function `message-fill-paragraph` in `message-mode`.  `message-fill-paragraph` acts differently for the header part and the rest of the message.  The fill adds extra whitespace at the beginning of lines.  The separation of the parts is given by the string given by the customizable variable `mail-header-separator` which has the default value "--text follows this line--".

Example:

Have the following text in a buffer in message mode (and `fill-column` 72):

```
I am sorry about your difficulties with git push.  It is true that in this situation
--text follows this line--
I am sorry about your difficulties with git push.  It is true that in this situation
```

M-q on each line starting with "I am sorry" yields:

```
I am sorry about your difficulties with git push.  It is true that in this
    situation
--text follows this line--
I am sorry about your difficulties with git push.  It is true that in
this situation
```