# Use message mode without headers

Tags: message-mode

I would like to edit e-mail messages without the header (!) in message mode.  If I open a file in message mode and it does not have the usual e-mail headers, then `M-q` filling does not work as I discovered in [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/41720/what-is-this-m-q-behaviour-in-emacs-26-1-message-mode).  In that question I learned that the header separator can be customized, but what if there is no header and no header separator at all?

I understand that sending the mail will not work without this header, but I send the mail on a different route. Actually, this is part of trying to use Emacs as the external editor for MailMate which works fine, except that I have not found a mode in which I can edit e-mail with font-locking for quote depth etc.  Probably this should be a minor mode for editing e-mail which does not exist yet.  notmuch-mode, mu4e-mode and org-msg all seem to be based on message mode and behave the same wrt. the header.

So is it possible to use message mode without a header?

Comment: I already tried to set the variable `mail-header-separator` to an empty string or just a space. This does not work.

Answer (score 1):

> So is it possible to use message mode without a header?

Would narrowing to the body work in your use case? See [`(info "(emacs) Narrowing")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Narrowing.html).  For example, you could `C-c C-b` (`message-goto-body`), `C-SPC` (`set-mark-command`), `M->` (`end-of-buffer`), `C-x n n` (`narrow-to-region`). To undo the narrowing, you could `C-x n w` (`widen`).

Here's a command that does this in one go:

```el
(defun my-message-narrow-to-body ()
  "Narrow buffer to Message body."
  (interactive)
  (narrow-to-region (save-excursion (message-goto-body) (point))
                    (point-max)))
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this does something else. I have a buffer with just the content of the e-mail, no header. `(message-goto-body)` takes me to the beginning of the buffer, then the narrowing is a no-op. The function `message-fill-paragraph` will behave as if I'm in the header because I am before the header separator (which never appears in the buffer).

Comment: Ah, I was thinking of the case where the headers are still there, but you can hide them by narrowing. I don't know why you would want or expect a major mode to work outside of its intended context.

Comment: I don’t know of any minor mode to do what I want: Be like message mode when editing the body. There is org-msg minor mode which I just discovered and I will have to try.